# Determine if an integer is greater than or equal to a list of integers in powershell

Tags: powershell, nested-loops

I have two lists of numbers and I want to compare list A to list B in such a way that I go through list A line by line and determine if that number is less than the number in B and then move to the next like of B and repeat.

If the number in A is found to be less than B I would like to return the number in A along with the "match" from B.

I've been trying nested loops and haven't gotten off the ground with this.

Any suggestions for me to try would be very helpful.

Thanks!

This is my "code" if you want to call it that.

```
$chrIVsite = @("322592","425559","427431") 
$SNPCsite = @("28860","43205","279260","481810")

    foreach ($read in $chrIVsite) 
{
    foreach ($site in $SNPCsite) {
if ($_.read -le $_.SNPCsite)
    {"$_.read"+"`t"+"$_.SNPCsite"
    }
 } }
export-csv 'testing.txt' -delimiter "`t" -notype
```

My expected outcome would be:

425559   481810

427431   481810

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: What you mean with return the number in A? You mean delete? Provide us an example of two list with the expected output.

Comment: still unsure of your desired result, but try replacing `$_.read` with `$read` and `$_.snpcsite` with `$site`

Comment: That did it @AnthonyStringer Thanks!  I had a hard time articulating what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AnthonyStringer I just had some simple issues.

This code:

```
$chrIVsite = @("322592","425559","427431")
$SNPCsite = @("28860","43205","279260","481810","481812","481814")

 foreach ($read in $chrIVsite)
{
 foreach ($site in $SNPCsite) {
 if ([int]$read -le [int]$site)
 {"$read"+"`t"+"$site"
 }
 } }
```

My out put looks like this:

```
322592  481810
322592  481812
322592  481814
425559  481810
425559  481812
425559  481814
427431  481810
427431  481812
427431  481814
```